# Configuring a local network that is only accessible via a single entry point

Tags: networking, ssh, dhcp

This seems to be fairly related to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/573752/is-it-possible-to-make-one-public-ip-point-at-different-servers-within-a-local-n), but I have some slight caveats.

I am making a network of Raspberry Pi devices at a university, however I have run out of available wall ethernet ports and the university's policy forbids any kind of hub or switch (and I don't want to buy additional hardware to make them wireless).  What I was hoping to do was to make one of the Pi's accessible via SSH, and then be able to access the other Pi's on the network through that public interface.

To connect them all together I'll need to use a hub/switch (whichever I have handy), but I want it to be completely local so that I don't get yelled at by the university's IT staff.

I do need to be able to access all via SSH, so I'm open to suggestions for doing this, but this kind of setup is a bit outside of my comfort zone when configuring networks/IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a very bad idea to attempt this without 2 network interfaces on the PI that is the connection point to the universities network.

I'll explain this setup first, then speculate on how this might be possible without 2 network interfaces, as the basic idea is the same.  Note that my advise is generic as, while I am pretty good with Linux and imbedded routers, I've never used a PI (but have used similar devices) -

## If you have 2 interfaces on the "Gateway" PI

Set up 1 interface externally, then use NAT (iptables MASQUERADE) and ip_forwarding to allow traffic on the LAN to be NATTED to appear to come from the gateway PI.   You will want to run a different network on the PI LAN subnet to the normal uni network - This would typically be one of 3 ranges - 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16 or 172.16.0.0/12

## If you only have a single interface on the PI

NOTE: I DO NOT ADVISE THIS - THE RISK OF MAKING A MISTAKE AND STUFFING UP THE UNI NETWORK IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING OR MAKE A MISTAKE IS VERY LARGE.

You might be able to cable this up with a managed switch - The idea would be to set up 2 VLANS - One for the Internal Network on the Gateway PI, one for the external network.    Lets call these VLAN1 - for the Uni Network and VLAN2 for your PI LAN.    You would set the PI gateway up as a trunk port on  the switch, so that eth0.1  listens on the Uni network, and eth0.2 offers services to the PI's.   You would then set up a port (Say port 1) on the switch so that it is untagged and connected on VLAN1 - and plug this into the Uni.   Other then this first port and the Trunk port, all other ports would be on VLAN2.   In this way, you are using the switch to effectively create multiple interfaces on the switch as if they were on the PI.

## Another thought

The easiest way to do this though, would be to scrounge an Ethernet router, and use that to separate the Uni network and your PI lan.  If the devices only need to see out (but don't need to be externally accessed), thats all you need - if they need to be externally accessed the easiest way to do this would be to ensure the router can take DD-WRT, flash this onto it and then use OpenVPN to set up a VPN connection into your lan.

Comment: So I do have an old Linksys router collecting dust.  I would need to be able to manage each Pi.  By default they take Raspbian, but I'm 99.99% certain I can put any Linux distro I want on there.  So if I went with 'Another Thought,' then I'm basically just creating a subnet and a VPN to that subnet?

Comment: A linksys router is a good candidate for DD-WRT - and its probably better then Raspian on it for this purpose, as thats what DD-WRT is good at.  Your description is correct in the loosest of terms (but technically incorrect).  You are creating a new separate network segment [ which you will map to a subnet, but its important that its a different segment so it does not interfere with the Uni network.  You use NAT to isolate the new Segment/Subnet behind the LAN interface, and then use VPN to connect into that)

Comment: I see.  I meant that the Pi can use Raspbian or any distro...I assumed DD-WRT would go on the router.  I'll look into how DD-WRT can be used to setup NAT/VPN and will go from there.

Comment: Would you consider this guide to be approximately what you're describing?  https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN_on_Dedicated_Wireless_Access_Point_(VAP)

Comment: No, that link is pretty irrelevant. Do devices plugged in to the uni network get world-reachable adddtessed, or do they start with one of 10.x.x.x , 192.168.x.x or 172.[16-32].x.x?

Comment: They're behind a firewall, but accessible if appropriate ports are opened up (141.x.x.x).

Comment: In that case you want to set up an OpenVPN server - look at http://www.howtogeek.com/64433/how-to-install-and-configure-openvpn-on-your-dd-wrt-router/